# Highlighting column in table OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it could be possible to make a script, that `on column click`, highlighted the column, instead of just highlighting it on `hover`.

**Right now i have made this CSS**

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  
  table {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  td, th {
      position: relative;
  }
  td:hover::before { 
      background-color: #eee;
      content: '';  
      height: 100%;
      left: -5000px;
      position: absolute;  
      top: 0;
      width: 10000px;   
      z-index: -2;        
  }
  td:hover::after { 
      background-color: rgb(255, 218, 170);
      content: '';  
      height: 10000px;    
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;  
      top: -5000px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;        
  }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Could it be possible to make a `script` that did this, just to columns:

```js
function highlight_row() {
  var table = document.getElementById("testresultsTable");
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    // Take each cell
    var cell = cells[i];
    // do something on onclick event for cell
    cell.onclick = function() {
      // Get the row id where the cell exists
      
      var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
        if(row !== rowId) {
        }
      }
      var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowId];
      if (rowSelected.classList.contains("selected")) {
          rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "";
          rowSelected.classList.remove("selected");
      } else {
        rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        rowSelected.classList.add("selected");
      }      
    }
  }
} //end of function
window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```html
<table id = 'testresultsTable' style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**So the question is:** How can I make somthing like the row select script, just for columns. So when I click on `Firstname, Lastname or Age`, the column is selected, and can also be unselected if I click again.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear on the question?

Comment: I did now, sorry.

Comment: So whenever the row is selected you also what the column to get selected as well right?

Comment: No, the `row select` is an example, When i `click`, on the column title, lets say `FirstName`, then that column, not the title, will be highlighted with a color, and if it's clicked again it would remove the highlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the index of clicked `td` and then select all `th` and `td` with that index and apply css.

```js
function highlight_row() {
  var table = document.getElementById("testresultsTable");
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    cell.onclick = function() {
      const parentTds = this.parentElement.children;
      const clickedTdIndex = [...parentTds].findIndex(td => td == this);
      const columns = document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child(${clickedTdIndex+1}), th:nth-child(${clickedTdIndex+1})`);
      document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(col => col.classList.remove('selected'));
      columns.forEach(col => {
        col.classList.add('selected');
      });
    }
  }
}

window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="testresultsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

-- Edit --

```js
function highlight_row() {
  var table = document.getElementById("testresultsTable");
  var tdsth = table.querySelectorAll("th, td");

  for (var i = 0; i < tdsth.length; i++) {
    var cell = tdsth[i];
    cell.onclick = function() {
      const children = this.parentElement.children;
      const clickedThIndex = [...children].findIndex(th => th == this);
      const columns = document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child(${clickedThIndex + 1}), th:nth-child(${clickedThIndex + 1})`);
      columns.forEach(col => {
        if (col.classList.contains('selected'))
          col.classList.remove('selected');
        else
          col.classList.add('selected');
      });
    }
  }
}

window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

td,
th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="testresultsTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks great! Would it be possible to select multiple, and also be able to unhighlight, the column if user clicks again, like in the `row example`?

Comment: @Mads - Do you want `click` on the `th` only? I mean the column should be highlighted only when clicked on `th` and not on `td`. See edit.

Comment: That was my intention, but when i think about it, `td`, is better, because my table can be very long, and it would be stupid if the user had to scoll all the way up to the `th`, to highlight the column. So `td`, if perfect!

Comment: @Mads - See edit, I have added both `td` and `th`. If you do not want `th`, then remove `th` from `table.querySelectorAll("th, td")`.

Comment: This is cool, but unfortunately it fails ending up highlighting completely wrong cells when using complex rowspan and colspan rules. I assume there's no simple fix to make it work with rowspan and colspan, or is there? Because of combined cells, the index numbers seem to be very different in each row.